# AngularJS ngrepeat refresh with post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

First of all i'm new to AngularJS and stackoverflow so i'm very open minded. My problem is that i have a table that has 3 items that use the ng-blur directive to call a save function
 UI

```
<div ng-controller="measureController">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h3>RatingYear</h3>
    <select ng-model="ratingYear" ng-change="getMeasures()">
        <option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
    </select>
</div> 
<!-- this is going to be the container for each measure-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading">Measures for {{ratingYear}}</div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Active</th>
                <th>Order</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="measure in measureList track by measure.MeasureId">
                <td class="col-md-1">{{measure.Code}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-5">{{measure.Name}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-4"><textarea ng-model="measure.Action" ng-disabled="!measure.Active" ng-blur="save(measure)"></textarea></td>
                <td class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="measure.Active" ng-model="measure.Active" ng-change="save(measure)" /></td>
                <td class="col-md-1"><input class="form-control" ng-model="measure.Order" ng-disabled="!measure.Active" ng-blur="save(measure)" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

  </div>
```

Controller

```
function measureController($scope, $http) {
$scope.years = [2014,2015, 2016 ];

//get Measures Per Year
$scope.getMeasures = function () {
    $http.get('/api/measure/' + $scope.ratingYear)
         .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             $scope.measureList = data;
             $scope.$apply();
             //$scope.loading = false;
         })
         .error(function () {
             $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading measures!";
             $scope.loading = false;
         });

};

//Edit Measure
$scope.save = function () {
    $scope.loading = true;
    var uMeasure = this.measure;
    var active = uMeasure.Active ? 1 : 0;
    $http.post('/api/measure/' + uMeasure.MeasureId + '/status/' + active, uMeasure)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.measureList.push(data);
            $scope.$digest();
        })
        .error(function (data,status, headers, config) {
            alert("You failed misserably"+data);
        });

};
}
```

I want to be able to refresh the measureList every time save has been called  with the new object that has been inserted, that is the modify copy of the existing, right now is creating multiple copies of the same  one in the database  and i can only see it when i reload the page or change the value in ratingYear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, i would recommend you to use Services or Factories to get a nice abstraction layer between your controller and the actual raw data. This will make your api calls (like get a list of measurements) reusable and maintanable.

Comment: I will take look at both of them, thanks